# Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)

Tags: domain-name-system, centos7, bind

I am on VPS using CentOS7 with CyberPanel. Today after updating the Custom Nameserver details; I have got an error when I am trying to restart/reload BINDS. Here is the error message:

[root@scandalous-cats ~]# systemctl start named.service
Job for named.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status named.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@scandalous-cats ~]# systemctl status named.service
● named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-02-21 20:56:37 UTC; 23s ago
Process: 11595 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -u named -c ${NAMEDCONF} $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 11593 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ ! "$DISABLE_ZONE_CHECKING" == "yes" ]; then /usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z "$NAMEDCONF"; else echo "Checking of zone files is disabled"; fi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 21 20:56:37 scandalous-cats.com named[11596]: initializing GeoIP Country (IPv4) (type 1) DB
Feb 21 20:56:37 scandalous-cats.com named[11596]: GEO-106FREE 20180327 Build 1 Copyright (c) 2018 MaxMind Inc All Rights Reserved
Feb 21 20:56:37 scandalous-cats.com named[11596]: initializing GeoIP Country (IPv6) (type 12) DB
Feb 21 20:56:37 scandalous-cats.com named[11596]: GEO-106FREE 20180605 Build 1 Copyright (c) 2018 MaxMind Inc All Rights Reserved
Feb 21 20:56:37 scandalous-cats.com named[11596]: GeoIP City (IPv4) (type 2) DB not available
Feb 21 20:56:37 scandalous-cats.com named[11596]: GeoIP City (IPv4) (type 6) DB not available
Feb 21 20:56:37 scandalous-cats.com systemd[1]: named.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 21 20:56:37 scandalous-cats.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS).
Feb 21 20:56:37 scandalous-cats.com systemd[1]: Unit named.service entered failed state.
Feb 21 20:56:37 scandalous-cats.com systemd[1]: named.service failed.

I am unable to figure-out the actual fault as well how to fix it. I need help regarding this and for fixing it.
Please help me.
Regards,

Comment: Check the logs.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I have checked Error Log but no one errors shows related with BINDS.

Comment: From the logs it shows you use the geolocation feature with some geo IP data... that does not exist on file. Maybe not the cause of your problem, but you should fix that (either download the map at relevant location, or change configuration not to use this feature). Also questions about specific panels are considered offtopic here.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks for guidelines, I am trying my best to get it, If I can't do that then I came here again.